# How to avoid null values from insertion into the database?

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

This question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074398/how-to-get-values-from-checkbox-and-pass-it-to-the-another-jsp-page/56077119#56077119).

I have created many input boxes using a for loop. from this whatever user type value, is get into another JSP page. from the input box values are getting properly.

But at the time of insertion that values into the database inserted as a blank or null. only if user type first input boxes in sequential order(first input box,second input box, third input box) then only value is getting inserted properly as per the expected results.

Even i'm checking the conditions also that is it contain null values or not. but still It'll will get inserted null values.

The main expected result is if user type particular value into the textbox then the value get inserted properly not the blank values get inserted into database.

```
<!-----new.jsp---------------------------------------------->

    <%
        for(int i = 0; i<ar.size(); i++)
        {
            %><span class="left-check"><%=ar.get(i)%></span><%

    %>
            <!--name=abc will be used in jsp to get value selected in checkboxes-->

            <input id ="<%=idcounter%>" type="checkbox" name = "abc" value="<%=ar.get(i)%>" />
            <input class = "left-marg-input7 size" id ="<%=idcounter%>" type="text" name = "abc_val" /><br><br>

    <%
        idcounter++;
        }
    %>
  </center><br><br>                                 
            <center><button type= "submit" name="action" >SIGN UP</button></center>
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then the Next jsp page is :

```
<!------insertdata.jsp---------------------------------------------->

<html>
<%

String check[]= request.getParameterValues("abc");
String checkval[] = request.getParameterValues("abc_val");
String check_str = "";
String checkval_str = "";

    if(check != null && checkval != null)
    {
            // there might be more one checkbox selected so, using loop    
        for(int i=0; i<check.length;i++)
        {
            // printing values selected from
            check_str = check[i].toString();
            checkval_str = checkval[i].toString();
            if(checkval_str != null)
            {
                 %><script>alert(<%=checkval_str%>);</script><%
                 st.executeUpdate("insert into user_assign_leave(org_email,user_email,leave_name,assign_leave,balance_leave)values('"+org_email+"','"+email+"','"+check_str+"','"+checkval_str+"','"+checkval_str+"')");
            }
            st.executeUpdate("insert into user_assign_leave(org_email,user_email,leave_name,assign_leave,balance_leave)values('"+org_email+"','"+email+"','"+check_str+"','"+checkval_str+"','"+checkval_str+"')");
        }
    }
    st.executeUpdate("insert into user(org_name,org_email,name,email,mobile,custom_ID,pass)values('"+org_name+"','"+org_email+"','"+username+"','"+email+"','"+contactno+"','"+customer_id+"','"+password+"')");

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change to a JSP method that isn't susceptible to SQL injection and your problem could go away.

Comment: Please can you explain me in brief i didn't get that.

Comment: During the formatting of the post, I've noticed that there's a single `}` in your second code block that isn't connected to a statement, that could cause a crash, skipping the code entirely.

Comment: no it's from the try block code. I did not show that code here. :) because it will get more lengthy that's why.

Comment: Ah, my bad then. Good to know. It's a bit doubtful in situations like these whether code should be included or excluded though. So I'll just have to assume it's not the cause of the excluded code.

Comment: Check for all  values of `checkval_str` before inserting i.e : `if(checkval_str!=null){ //insert checkval_str value  }else{//don’t insert checkval_str value }`,if not null then only allow to `insert` value in database,else don’t insert `checkval_str` value.

Comment: yes i have tried that but in this case value is printing but the null value is also printing

Comment: here i observe that it's insertion format is similar like user type in input box. e.g- in first input box user type a value then in third input box then in fifth input box. in that value is inserted in table similar to that way no condition checking is going behind. like it will give output like 1,3,5 fields are inserted rest of the 2,4 remaining empty.

Comment: M i do it right for the input boxes ? Because i have done in similar way that you have showed me for checkboxes.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why empty values are getting in if(checkval_str!=null) condition block displaying empty/null values. Look i have write one alert for that "%><script>alert(<%=checkval_str%>);</script><%"

Comment: You didn’t assign any value to `checkval_str` in your above code, also if that field is `null` put database code in else part where you will not insert `balance_leave` field.

Comment: sorry i have missed to write here in this code checkval_str = checkval[i].toString(); now i have put this line here

Comment: if i put In else part then i will get null values so? i want to put checkbox values at a time with input box values.

Comment: What no offence  ? your comment is definitely offensive. and i'm new to JSP then whats the problem ? and don't judge by the name i have done lot of classes i ask their also but they also don't know then ??

Comment: @Swati Do you know the solution ?

Comment: @MOJOJOJOJO do you want any  one of `input` can be empty or both `checkbox` and `input`  should have values ?

Comment: both checkbox and input should contains values don't want empty or null values if user miss to type values in any input box. only typed values i want suppose if user type values in 3 input boxes out of 7 (whichever it is) then in array where we getting values in jsp page there only 3 values should get. [no blank or null values should get into array]

Comment: @Swati can you give me any sugession that how do i do that?

Comment: you need to have another `for` loop for checking input values and then insert value in database .